# Interpreting a condition about CDF

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

Let F(X) be a strictly increasing CDF which admits a positive density f(x).
Is the condition x/F(x) being non-increasing (aka, weakly decreasing) equivalent to saying that F(x) is convex?
If not, what is a somewhat intuitive meaning for this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent in the sense that neither condition is ever true (for all $x$).  A CDF must satisfy $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = 1$ , so in particular $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x/F(x) = +\infty$ and it can't be non-increasing.
Similarly, if $F(x)$ is convex and $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$ then
$F(x) \ge 1$ for all $x$, and this can't happen for a CDF.

But if you're talking about these conditions being true on a bounded interval, they are not equivalent either.  You might note that $F(x)/x$ is the slope of the secant line from $(0,0)$ to the graph of the function at $(x,F(x))$.  It's not hard to sketch examples where on some interval
$x/F(x)$ is decreasing but $F$ is not convex, or where $F$ is convex but $x/F(x)$ is not decreasing.  In the picture below, for about $6.3 \le x \le 7.8$ we have $x/F(x)$ decreasing but $F$ not convex; for $3.2 \le x \le 4.2$ and we have $x/F(x)$ increasing but $F$ convex.

[image]

EDIT: Let's say $x > 0$.  $x/F(x)$ is decreasing for $x$ in some interval if in that interval the curve $y = F(x)$ crosses the secant line from $(0,0)$ to $(x,F(x))$ from below, as in the following picture (curve in red, secant line in blue):

[image]

It is increasing if in that interval the curve crosses the secant line from above, as in the following picture:

[image]

At a local maximum or minimum of $x/F(x)$ the tangent line to $y = F(x)$ passes through the origin.   You can have a local maximum where the curve is convex, or a local minimum where the curve is concave, but you can't have a local maximum where the curve is strictly concave or a local minimum where the curve is strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I had in mind a bounded interval. More precisely, x is in some interval [0,a] for a>0.
If F(x)=x^(k), then x/F(x) being non-increasing is equivalent to k being greater or equal than 1; that is, F is (weakly) convex. But I see now that this can't be true for all distributions on [0,a].
What is then the intuitive meaning of x/F(x) being non-increasing? I thought it roughly meant that higher values of x are more likely than lower values of x but this seems incomplete/incorrect now.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but from your two last plots it seems indeed that x/F(x) is decreasing for x iff F(x) is convex.

Comment: It's just a coincidence that the function is convex in one plot and concave in the other.  I could easily have reversed these.